# Linked git submodule repository changed the name. How can I get the history of this renaming change?

Tags: git, tfs

I have a *parent* Git repository that has a few submodules declared in .gitmodules file.
Suddenly, after trying to switch between my branches in *parent* I receive the following error:

> remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier *submodule1* does not exist
> or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.

I realized that this repository was either renamed (found several similar names) or deleted. How can I figure out what happened to this repository? Is it possible to see the repository renaming history?

Comment: `git log -p .gitmodules`

Comment: @phd, My question is mostly about the submodule1 repository name history itself, not related to my repository which use it in .gitmodules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't": the situation is analogous to the one where you have a phone number for a service company, and you call it and nobody answers (or you get the [Intercept](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/IC_SIT.ogg) [Special Information Tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_information_tone).  All you can tell from this is "it's gone".

Of course, you *can* hire a private detective (such as Mr. Google) to try to find out why and where.  But that's not something Git does for you.